# How to parse this XML : <timestamp time="1545366296721848" delay="0"/>

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

Server returns XML file that contain: `<timestamp time="1545366296721848" delay="0"/>` I need to parse it in order to get "1545366296721848" value. How to do it using javascript or jquery?

Ok, got it now, I should have to convert it to a string first, using: `document.documentElement.outerHTML;` I'm new to all of this, so it took time to figure it out :)

Comment: Here you go: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its pretty straight. Use the DOM Parser for this.

```
var input = '<timestamp time="1545366296721848" delay="0"/>';
var parser = new DOMParser();
var oDOM = parser.parseFromString(input, "application/xml");

console.log(oDOM.documentElement.attributes[0].nodeValue);
console.log(oDOM.documentElement.attributes[1].nodeValue);
```